# How to connect score throughout the app project?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need the user to see the score in the main menu, the select level and in the answer quiz questions. How would I implement the score, should I make a new objective-c file and import the specified files?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information in this question to provide any kind of meaningful answer. Please say what you have tried already, and post some code to give some kind of context as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add more details about your project in order to get a good answer.

From your question I can assume that you're building a game and that your problem is making some variables accessible from more than one viewController.

Depending on how you built your game, there are more ways to make that possible. If you have a class User (which stores your info about the current user), that would be the perfect place to store the score of the current user. And you would need to have a method, which would be called for example with `[User currentUser]` which returns the current user which is logged in. And you could call that method in whatever viewController you want.

Or, much easier (but not that nice), if you don't have the concept of User (and by that, I mean a class which stores info about the current user), you can store the score in `NSUserDefaults`, get it form there whenever you need it and update it in there when you modify it.

To store a value in `NSUserDefaults` try something like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:yourScore forKey:@"Score"];
```

To get a value from `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSInteger score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Score"];
```

Please note that the option with NSUserDefaults is not OOP-ish and not nice in terms of code design quality. But it should do the trick. And given the small amount of information in the original question, I cannot provide a better answer.